# JQuery Gallery next button not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, gallery

I am trying to create a basic gallery using JQuery.

The basic idea is that all image files are called x.png (where x is a number), and the program adds a number to the current number creating x+1.png and so on.

The code i have is:

```
function gal2(){
    var amount = $(".imagelist > img").length;
    var next = $("#display").attr('src').replace('.png', '');
    if ($("#display").attr('src').replace('.png', '') >= amount) {
        $("#display").attr('src', next+".png");
        next++;
    } else {
        $("#display").attr('src', next+".png");
        next++;
    };
}
```

gal2 is called on a button press `<input type="button" onclick="gal2()">`,
`.imagelist` is a div containing the images, 
`#display` is the main image being shown, 
[Example Website](http://htmlforschool.netau.net/gallery.html)

The problem is that nothing happens except if one is selected than it will back to the original one every time.
**P.S: It's for a year 9 secondary school project**

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the most important part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some edits to your script and now it work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/qwmt7Lep/2/

```
function gal2(){
    var amount = $(".imagelist > img").length;
    var current = parseInt($("#display").attr('src').replace('.png', ''));
    var next = current + 1;
    if (current < amount) {
        $("#display").attr('src', next+".png");
    } else {
        $("#display").attr('src', "1.png");
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes it already an int, I will edit it. but any way it will not make any problem.

Comment: @ahmed-salama so instead of adding to a basic variable it tracks the current image being displayed?